# Multiple JSON requests in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I wish to fetch data for an array of URLs that return JSON data. I am trying the following code:

```
for (int i =0; i<numberOfDays; i++)
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[wordURLs objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[wordURLs objectAtIndex: i]);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

'wordURLs' are the array of URLs and in my 'fetchedData:' method, I save the returned JSON data to a plist file.

The issue is that for all number of times that the loop runs, the data is returned for only one/two particular URLs (i.e. say for the urls at indices at 1 and 3, or 1 and  2 etc). I log and see that the URLs are different for each time the 'data' variable is initialized.

What is a better way of doing this?

I have used NSJSONSerialization for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are much better ways of doing this. The problem with what you are trying to do is that it is synchronous, which means your app will have to wait for this action to be completed before it can do anything else. I definitely would recommend looking into making this into an asynchronous call by simply using `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequests`, and setting up delegates for them.

They are relatively simple to set up and manage and will make your app run a million times smoother.

I will post some sample code to do this a little later once I get home.

**UPDATE**

First, your class that is calling these connections will need to be a delegate for the connections in the interface file, so something like this.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate> {
    NSMutableData *pageData;
    NSURLConnection *pageConnection;
}
```

Then you will need to create/initialize the necessary variables in you implementation

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
       pageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
       NSURLRequest *pageRequest= [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:pageURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:4];
       pageConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:pageRequestdelegate:self];
}
```

Then you also need the delegate functions that will get called as the data is retrieved.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (connection == pageConnection) {
        [pageData appendData:data];
    }
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if (connection == pageConnection) {
        // Do whatever you need to do with the data
    }
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if (connection == pageConnection) {
        // Do something since the connection failed
    }
}
```

Of course this example only includes one URL being loaded, but you could make it as many as you want. You will of course have to keep track of all of the necessary `NSURLConnections` so you know where to put the data you received, as well as what actions to take in case of a failure or the connection being completed successfully, but that is not a hard extension from what I have given.

If you see any glaring errors or something does not work, please let me know.